# Вывести элемент ответа json на python

Tags: python, массивы, json, requests

Всем привет, только начал работать с реквестами на питоне. Пытался загуглить свой вопрос, но не нашел.
Ближе к делу: на мой запрос приходит ответ вида

```
  "id": 11631253,
  "created_at": "2018-10-13T08:13:38.809469028Z",
  "phone": "+79000381454",
  "product": "vkontakte",
  "price": 21,
  "status": "RECEIVED",
  "expires": "2018-10-13T08:28:38.809469028Z",
  "sms": [
      {
        "id":3027531,
        "created_at":"2018-10-13T08:20:38.809469028Z",
        "date":"2018-10-13T08:19:38Z",
        "sender":"VKcom",
        "text":"VK: 09363 - use this code to reclaim your suspended profile.",
        "code":"09363"
      }
  ],
  "forwarding": false,
  "forwarding_number": "",
  "country":"russia"
}
```

Я могу вывести поле sms при помощи `print(response.json()['sms'])`. В документации сказано, что поле 'sms' это array. И я не могу понять как вывести элемент 'text' из 'sms'.

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите как это сделать!

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо выбрать первый элемент массива:

```
print(response.json()['sms'][0]['text'])
```

Comment: Либо перебрать все элементы массива - а вдруг их там несколько